Rabbit MQ None of the specified endpoints were reachable only on AWS EC2 Fedora
I have a larger project using RabbitMQ, and I am trying to run it on AWS. If I run my project locally, on Mac, Windows, or Dockerised Linux it works fine, but on EC2 about 80% of the time I get the following error:
fail: IndexerLib.Repository.RabbitMQConnection[0]
      Error initializing RabbitMQ connection: None of the specified endpoints were reachable
fail: IndexerLib.Repository.RabbitMQConnection[0]
      Exception Type: RabbitMQ.Client.Exceptions.BrokerUnreachableException
Failed to connect to RabbitMQ
Error executing index 0 0 sepolia production
Recommended usage is: index <from> <to> <chain> <env>
fail: IndexerLib.Repository.RabbitMQConnection[0]
      Stack Trace:    at RabbitMQ.Client.ConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(IEndpointResolver endpointResolver, String clientProvidedName)
         at RabbitMQ.Client.ConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(String clientProvidedName)
         at RabbitMQ.Client.ConnectionFactory.CreateConnection()
         at IndexerLib.Repository.RabbitMQConnection.Init() in /home/ec2-user/emergence-core/IndexerTool/IndexerLib/Repository/RabbitMQConnection.cs:line 50
fail: IndexerLib.Repository.RabbitMQConnection[0]
      Inner Exception: The operation has timed out.
fail: IndexerLib.Repository.RabbitMQConnection[0]
      Inner Exception Type: System.TimeoutException
fail: IndexerLib.Repository.RabbitMQConnection[0]
      Inner Exception Stack Trace:    at RabbitMQ.Util.BlockingCell`1.WaitForValue(TimeSpan timeout)
         at RabbitMQ.Client.Impl.SimpleBlockingRpcContinuation.GetReply(TimeSpan timeout)
         at RabbitMQ.Client.Impl.ModelBase.ConnectionStartOk(IDictionary`2 clientProperties, String mechanism, Byte[] response, String locale)
         at RabbitMQ.Client.Framing.Impl.Connection.StartAndTune()
         at RabbitMQ.Client.Framing.Impl.Connection.Open(Boolean insist)
         at RabbitMQ.Client.Framing.Impl.Connection..ctor(IConnectionFactory factory, Boolean insist, IFrameHandler frameHandler, String clientProvidedName)
         at RabbitMQ.Client.Framing.Impl.Connection..ctor(IConnectionFactory factory, Boolean insist, IFrameHandler frameHandler, ArrayPool`1 memoryPool, String clientProvidedName)
         at RabbitMQ.Client.Framing.Impl.AutorecoveringConnection.Init(IFrameHandler fh)
         at RabbitMQ.Client.Framing.Impl.AutorecoveringConnection.Init(IEndpointResolver endpoints)
         at RabbitMQ.Client.ConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(IEndpointResolver endpointResolver, String clientProvidedName)

Here is the connection code:
using EmergenceCore.Config;
using EmergenceCore.Logging;
using RabbitMQ.Client;

namespace IndexerLib.Repository;

public class RabbitMQConnection : IRabbitMQConnectionProvider
{
    public IConnection Connection => connection;
    
    private IConnection connection;
    private readonly ILogger logger;
    private readonly IConfigProvider ConfigProvider;

    public RabbitMQConnection(IConfigProvider configProvider, ILoggerProvider loggerProvider)
    {
        logger = loggerProvider.GetLogger<RabbitMQConnection>();
        ConfigProvider = configProvider;
    }
    
    public bool Init()
    {
        try
        {
            var rabbitMqConfig = ConfigProvider.GetSectionValues("IndexerTool");
            var host = rabbitMqConfig["rabbitmq_host"];
            var username = rabbitMqConfig["rabbitmq_username"];
            var port = int.Parse(rabbitMqConfig["rabbitmq_port"]);

            var password = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("RABBITMQ_PASSWORD") ?? "";

            var factory = new ConnectionFactory
            {
                HostName = host,
                Ssl = new SslOption()
                {
                    Enabled = true,
                    ServerName = host,
                },
                UserName = username,
                Password = password,
                Port = port,
            };

            connection = factory.CreateConnection();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            logger.LogError($"Error initializing RabbitMQ connection: {e.Message}");
            logger.LogError($"Exception Type: {e.GetType().FullName}");
            logger.LogError($"Stack Trace: {e.StackTrace}");

            if (e.InnerException != null)
            {
                logger.LogError($"Inner Exception: {e.InnerException.Message}");
                logger.LogError($"Inner Exception Type: {e.InnerException.GetType().FullName}");
                logger.LogError($"Inner Exception Stack Trace: {e.InnerException.StackTrace}");
            }

            return false;
        }
        
        return true;
    }
}

I've done a lot of research and turned up no one with a similar issue so far, so hoping I may have more luck here. Thanks in advance.
I have tried hard coding in the credentials, and logging them out, they are definitely correct, proven since it works 20% of the time, but not posted them here for obvious reasons.
